# Why is XDebug causing page to stick loading in Visual Studio Code PHP Debug extension?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am attempting to debug php in Visual Studio Code. This is my first project after installing the PHP Debug extension (and also PHP and XDebug as dependencies). The page renders correctly if I have the PHP executable target the file in command prompt "C:\php>php -S 0.0.0.0:9000 c:\users\landerson\documents\vs_proj\php_example\index.php". However if I begin debugging in Visual Studio with configuration "Listen for XDebug", the page will be stuck loading until I stop the debugging process.

I am following Microsoft's blog entry explaining initial setup: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2016/02/11/configuring-visual-studio-code-for-php-development/. I suspect not fully understanding the instruction "Make sure to point your webserver root to your project and each time you request a PHP file" may be what is tripping me up.  I've tried with and without executing the command prompt entry. That seems to only effect what happens after I stop the debugging process. I've entered my phpinfo() results into https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and followed the instructions. I have neither an index.php nor a php.ini in C:\php and have both in c:\users\landerson\documents\vs_proj\php_example

index.php

```
<?php
$myvar = "Hello ";
$myvar = $myvar . "PHP World!";

echo $myvar;

?>
```

Bottom of php.ini

```
zend_extension = C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll

[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

C:\Users\landerson\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

```
{
    //"http.proxyStrictSSL": false,

    "php.validate.enable": true,
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
    "php.validate.run": "onType"
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

I would expect that at least without breakpoints the page would load and adding breakpoints would utilize the PHP Debug extension. It seems that Visual Studio Code is at least getting XDebug to begin listening on port 9000, but for whatever reason it isn't progressing as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up getting it to work by following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a14kN2u5nEk by Lyall van der Linde. Among other mistakes, I shouldn't have configured both the service and the extension to  the same port.

A little quirk at this time is as far as I can tell that XDebug doesn't have a release currently for PHP 32 bit version 7.3.1 so I ended up installing an old version of XAMPP (7.2.14). Old versions of the Windows installer are available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/. I have installed the most recent version of Visual Studio Code. I've added the PHP Debug extension to Visual Studio Code and reloaded the application.

Since IIS is using port 80, I opened XAMPP Control Panel and navigated to the master level Config, then Service and Port Settings and set, under the apache tab, the Service Name Apahce2.4 to Main Port 8080 and SSL Port 443. I edited C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and replaced "Listen 80" with "Listen 8080". Then I started the apache service in the XAMPP Control Panel.

I then added the folder "phptest" under C:\xampp\htdocs\ and opened said folder in VSCode. Added File test.php and added lines:

```
<?php

$a = 6;
$b = 3;
$c = 0;

$c = $a * $b;

echo $c;
```

I updated the VSCode User Settings as follows

```
{
    "php.validate.enable": true,
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
    "php.validate.run": "onType"
}
```

I opened the output of http://localhost:8080/phptest/test.php as “18”.

I opened http://localhost:8080/dashboard/phpinfo.php, copied the text of that page and pasted the results to the input form at https://xdebug.org/wizard.php. This prompted me to download the correct dll for XDebug (php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15.dll for me). I then edited C:\xampp\php\php.ini and appended to the end of the file:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15.dll
```

Due to the changing php.ini, I needed to stop and restart the Apache service in the XAMPP Control Panel. I then selected "Debug" under the left navigation of Visual Studio Code and added a PHP configuration "Listen for XDebug" and used the default launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

I added a breakpoint in test.php and started debugging in Visual Studio Code. I navigated in my browser to localhost:8080/phptest/test.php and my breakpoint was hit in Visual Studio Code allowing me to view the values of variables and step through the code.